# C++ program gets compiled in VC++ 2010 but not in Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++

I will not paste the whole program, but just the included files and the errors, as I am very sure, the error lies there itself!

Files included in VS 2010

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "vector"
#include "math.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <bitset>
```

Files included in Visual C++ 6.0

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include "iostream"
#include "conio.h"
#include "vector"
#include "math.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <bitset>
#include <String>
```

Well, there is just one difference, I added `#include <String>` in Visual C++ 2006, this particular file reduced  the error which read as

> error C2678: binary '!=' : no operator defined which takes a left-hand operand of type () 'class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >'
>    (or there is no acceptable conversion)

The other major errors I am still facing in VS2006 are

Line : `str.append(to_string((long double)(value)));`

Error: `error C2065: 'to_string' : undeclared identifier`

Line: `vector <vector <float>> distOfSectionPoint, momentAtSectionPoint, preFinalMoment, finalMoments, momentAtSectionPtOnPtLoadProfile ;`

Error: `error C2208: 'class std::vector' : no members defined using this type`

Can anyone explain what goes wrong in Visual C++ 2006??

Comment: Show us, at least the rows, where the errors occur. Can't tell much without any code.

Comment: You tagged this "vc6," which was released considerably earlier than 2006. Are you sure you're using the version you think you are?

Comment: What is this `#include <String>` which is not included in `VS2010`? Also, use `<>` for standard headers (like `vector`, `string`, etc.)

Comment: @KirilKirov: I tried using <> the errors do not reduce, please see the edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming `to_string` is `std::to_string`, then that's a C++11 function which won't be available in older compilers. You could cobble together something roughly equivalent, like

```
template <typename T>
std::string nonstd::to_string(T const & t) {
    std::ostringstream s;
    s << t;
    // For bonus points, add some error checking here
    return s.str();
}
```

The error involving `vector` is caused by the two closing angle-brackets, which older compilers would interpret as a single `>>` token. Add a space between them:

```
vector<vector<float> >
                    ^
```

It's not quite clear which compiler you're using, since there was no Visual C++ 2006. If you actually mean Visual C++ 6.0 (from 1998), then you're probably doomed. There have been two major language revisions since then, making it very difficult to write code supported by both that compiler, and modern compilers. If you mean 2005 or 2008, then just be careful to avoid C++11 features.

Comment: I have added the lines, where the error occurred, please see the edit

Comment: @vin: You'll need to add a space between the two `>` brackets for that code to work with older compilers.

Answer (score 4):

```
error C2065: 'to_string' : undeclared identifier
```

[`std::to_string()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) is a C++11 feature supported by VS2010. Any earlier versions of the Microsoft Compiler will not support it. An alternative is [`boost::lexical_cast`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

---

```
error C2208: 'class std::vector' : no members defined using this type
```

C++11 and VS2010 allow use of [`>>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Right_angle_bracket) but pre C++11 does not. Need to change to:

```
vector <vector <float> > distOfSectionPoint,
                    //^ space here
```

Comment: @vin, I have done. Or see Mike Seymour's suggestion if boost is not an option for you.